# How exactly memcache removes expired data?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

I am using [com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheService](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheService) to work with Google Memcache.

When storing a value, I set an expiration of 60 seconds. But the value is still returned from the cache even after several minutes.

The code for working with Memcache:

```
// Config
int expirationSeconds = 60;
Expiration expiration = Expiration.byDeltaSeconds(expirationSeconds);
MemcacheService memcache = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();

// Write operation
memcache.put(id, value, expiration);

// Read operation
memcache.get(id);
```

I am expecting the value to be absent in this case because the Memcache [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/memcache/#how_cached_data_expires) says that `An expired item is removed when someone unsuccessfully tries to retrieve it`.

Why the expired value is still returned from Memcache?

Comment: How exactly are you configuring Memcache? Please share a snippet of related code.

Comment: @Dmitry Grankin I have just tested the code that you have presented and everything is working fine for me (value is absent from Memcache and is returning null). Are you still experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation uses two words `evicted` and `removed` that could be understood to be [interchangeable](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/memcache/#how_cached_data_expires) but they [aren't](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/memcache/using#configuring_expiration):

> By default, all values remain in the cache as long as possible, until evicted due to memory pressure, removed explicitly by the app, or made unavailable for another reason (such as an outage).

And [in the note here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/memcache/#how_cached_data_expires) we can see how removal process works:

> The actual removal of expired cache data is handled lazily. An expired item is removed when someone unsuccessfully tries to retrieve it.

At the same place the eviction is explained like that:

> The value is evicted no later than this time, though it can be evicted earlier for other reasons. Increment the value stored for an existing key does not update its expiration time.

`Eviction` is something akin to soft removal where the value is unavailable but is still in the Memcache. `Removal` does the actual removal.

Comment: Ok, I got it. But in my case, an expired (evicted) value is still returned by `MemcacheService`. I wait two more times longer than an actual expiration time. 

The documentation says that an expired value is not returned (I expect `null` in my Java code), but a value is still returned. As for me, the behavior and the documentation are inconsistent.

Comment: Isn't it a waste of space to have expired data in the cache? For eg: if the `ttl` of a KV pair is 10 seconds, according to what you've mentioned, the object will not actually be removed after 10 seconds. It will be removed only when a user tries to retrieve it and will subsequently receive an unsuccessful `null` response.